# Using AutoFilter with Criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have hit a brick wall on this one, but I would like someone who can help me with autofilter and perhaps advanced filter (but not sure on this one) where I have one column that contains dates which also contains the value 'NULL' and another column that contains numbers plus the value 'NULL'. In this second column there can be duplicate numbers.

My criteria for the first column is to exclude the value 'NULL', but to also exclude dates less than 14. The criteria for the second column is to include ALL 'NULL' values, but where there are numbers ONLY to show unique numbers (or distinct in proper speak).

I am unsure how to do this and I haven't been able to find anything on the internet.

Can anyone help?

Comment: It's not 100% clear what you are after for the end result? Are you looking to just get the unique numbers associated with the 2nd column after filtering the first and the presence of the 'Null' if it exists? Can you post a sample workbook?

Comment: There is no relationship between the two columns. I have already had that conversation with the customer. In fact the value 'NULL' are in both columns but the columns are NOT connected

Comment: it's still not clear exactly what you are after? Is this two separate data sets? The 1st being the filtered column with NOT NULL or Date > 13 and the 2nd being the filterered column for NULL or DISTINCT NUMBER? Or is it 1 data with all four criteria applied?

Comment: It is one worksheet with 60 columns within it. One column has theses two actions: exclude NULL and should dates older than 14 days. The next column I will need to keep the NULLs and show distinct numbers

Comment: I have managed this with the dates but the date filtering is not working correctly because I am not seeing the dates correctly: ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$BV$65536).AutoFilter Field:=34, Criteria1:="<>NULL", Operator:=XlAnd, Criteria2"<" & Now()-14 Now is used because there is a time element

Comment: Because Now() - 14 is 14 seconds ago...   What do you mean exactly when you say Dates less than 14?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the macro recorder to get this code:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$6").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>NULL", _
    Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<5/14/2012"
```

That said, you will need to do this:

```
   ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$6").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>NULL", _
        Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<" & Date - 14
```

For the 2nd filter. Copy the column to a blank column and use the RemoveDuplicates function to get the Distinct List of numbers.

```
Intersect(UsedRange, Range("A1")).EntireColumn.Copy Range("Z1")
Intersect(UsedRange, Range("Z1")).EntireColumn.RemoveDuplicates(more args here that you will need to fill)
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I tried the date filter no dates were being filter out. I have read though that excel doesn't treat dates as per the regional settings. Please note I have changed date to now as I have a time in the data. Further, is there away I can avoid the column as I have some 10 worksheets to work with and the users are not looking to add an additional column which may cause errors.

Comment: Sorry, meant to put Range("Z1").EntireColumn.Delete after processing duplicates out. Also you can use whatever column you want. The idea is that you process what you need and then delete. The user never has to know. Also, when you say no dates were filtered out, is this because you have no data older than 14 days? Or is your column not formatted as a date?

Comment: I did a bit of digging around on the test data I was given it the former as oppose to the latter so its fine now. One thing I am not sure about if I copy the column to a blank column to remove the duplicates how do I ensure that the data I copy back goes to the right rows? Not sure on your suggested solution?

Comment: Here's the thing... I am not sure what you want to do with the unique rows that you need. There is no way to filter only unique instances of numbers in a row without affecting the entire data table. If you only caring about seeing the entire row of data once for a given number, then just remove duplicates based on that column. If you need your entire data set in tact and you want to capture and report the unique numbers, you can do that as I suggested, or in a similar manner and report them somewhere else. If your requirement is something else, let me know.

Comment: I get back to you tomorrow. I am going to sleep on it!